# Does IE8 support HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I have requirement where the client needs their website to be developed in [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) and [css3](/questions/tagged/css3). However it seems like [ie6](/questions/tagged/ie6), [ie7](/questions/tagged/ie7) don't support HTML5 and CSS3. The client said that HTML5 and CSS3 is supported in [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8), but I need to know to which degree it is actually supported.

Comment: There are JavaScript fixes out there that enable IE to support certain parts of HTML5 and especially CSS3. It might not matter at all though, depending on what elements of HTML5 and CSS3 your client wants on their website?

Answer (score 11):

- No browser supports all of HTML 5 or CSS 3
- Many browsers (including IE8) support some features added in HTML 5 or CSS 3
- All browsers support some of HTML 5
- All mainstream graphical browsers support some of CSS 3

Worry about what you want to achieve, then look for the optimal way to achieve it. Don't start with the tools available and then try to find a use for them.

Develop for the lowest common denominator and then [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) from there.

Comment: With 'LCD' being the 'Lowest common denominator', not 'LCD monitor' as in `@media screen {}` ;-)

Comment: I develop for the modern browsers first, then add if conditions to handle older browser quirks where it trips over on modern code. This ensures that at least the modern browsers will execute the most efficient code. And your not developing clunky slow code that executes slower than it needs to be for the users that are using up to date browsers. Why let a minority slow your code down for the majority.

Answer (score 4):

Try to look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) or [html5test](http://html5test.com/) websites.

Answer (score 3):

IE8 supports *nothing* of HTML5, that wasn't part of HTML4, since it was developed, before HTML5 became even a W3C draft.

CSS3: There is the one or other property, that didn't make it in CSS 2.1, that IE8 actually supports, like `text-wrap`. However, it's not worth mentioning it. Especially all the goodies like box shadows and rounded corners don't exist in IE8.

Look at the links in yojimbo87's answer for more details on supported properties.

What is worse, is that even IE9 doesn't support that much of HTML5. They focused on canvas, video and audio and claim it now to be "HTML5 ready". But, for example, all the new form fields are completely missing, not speaking of lots of new JavaScript APIs.

So, to put it in a nutshell, no, IE8 doesn't support HTML5. It can, however, display HTML5 documents, since the specification is written with fallback options for older browsers in mind.

Answer (score 1):

ie6 & ie7 have almost no support for html5 & css3.

Take a look at Quirksmode's compatibility table at:
http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

If you need to develop in html5 I would recommend taking a look at Modernizr. It is a javascript library that tests the users's browser and modifies the html/css to suit it's capabilities.
http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 specification is still in development phaze. You can try selling a client stuff, that is not yet developed.
As with InternetExplorer, then no, it supports just about 5% of HTML5 current specs.

Comment: "You can try selling a client stuff, that is not yet developed." That's pretty much all that the Marketing&Sales guys did at my previous job - "hey guys, we promised the client to prove P=NP by yesterday, so get coding" ;) HTML5 is stil in development, yes, but that doesn't apparently bother any of the browser makers.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 and CSS3 is not supported to a great extent on IE8. I would suggest you to use Firefox 4 from the 'Gecko' browser family or Google chrome or Safari (if you are on MacOSX) from the 'Webkit' browser family. They have great support for HTML5. Although I haven't tried it myself, I hear IE9 has excellent support for HTML5. But it runs only on Windows 7.

Firefox or Chrome would be my choice though.

Answer (score 0):

With current browser support of HTML5 and CSS3, your client must either a) be insane or b) not know what they're on about. While it is true that HTML5 and CSS3 are gaining support pretty quickly, the majority of browsers don't have good support for the more advanced features of the two techs, for example, `<audio>` and `<video>` aren't too widely supported. Neither is `<canvas>`. As for CSS3, quite a few bits of it are supported well, but IE users will have to do without.

As an additional note, IE6 is still in very heavy use in China, so if you're targeting that market, stick with the older, better supported technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually IE-8 support HTML-4, its better to use chrome,firfox or sefari for HTML-5. More you can see [here](http://www.podinaproduction.tk/2017/11/HTML5-CSS3.html)