# append class to body tag based on browser, compatibility etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using JavaScript and the jQuery library on my site. I want to append CSS classes to my `<body>` tag based with the following information:

- Browser
- Browser version
- Whether data URI/Base64 is supported
- HTML5 compatibility

Anyone know any JavaScript or jQuery plugins that could assist with this?

Comment: That's an HTML class. There is no such thing as a CSS class. The term sometimes gets used to mean "rule-set", "class selector", "any selector" and "property". This is confusing, so please don't use the term.

Comment: And, frankly, the only reason to use a class is so you can style things on a per-browser basis. Most of what you are looking for sounds like things you will be doing in JS, if you can't use [feature / object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) to check support, then you are better off keeping the data in a JS variable rather then stuffing it into the DOM.

Comment: You can't test for [HTML 5 compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497587/does-ie8-support-html5-and-css3/5497619#5497619) (at least not as a whole).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at modernizr [ http://www.modernizr.com/ ]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However modernizr does not check if a browser can work with base64-encoded images, or add the browser information to the class. Is is possible to extend modernizr for this?

Comment: Discussion on modernizr and base64 images: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/14

As for adding browser info to the class, have a look at: http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blogFiles/browserDetect.js
(You might want to edit it so it adds to the html tag instead of the body)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Note that Modernizr generally adds its classes to the `<html>` tag, not the body tag. That still works for the sort of thing you're trying to do.