# Background: color does not work in IE8

Tags: css

```
body {
    background: gray; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

header {
    background: green;
    border: 10px solid black;
}

nav {
    margin-top:10px;
    background: #62D99C;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Header and nav background does not work in IE8. It does work in Chrome and FF. What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Try using the hash tag - `background: #030303;` instead.

Comment: IE8 does not know the nav and header HTML5 elements. But - sorry - i don't have a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should apply `display:block` to the header and nav elements:

```
header {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  margin-top:10px;
  background: #62D99C;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

It seems you also need to include the following js:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

The reasons for this can be found here:

http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/

Put simply, IE8 doesn't support HTML5 elements by default, but by having this javascript execute *(only for IE8 or less)* it starts to recognise those elements. Most developers use some form of `html5 shim` to fix this.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Comment: @skyneon Have you read the link also? you'll probably need to include the conditional comment the writer talks about. This is because IE8 doesn't support HTML5 tags.

Comment: Now that you mentioned js fix, it works and I did read the article.  I can now use html5 tags in IE8. Thanks! Btw, it works without display:block.

Comment: @skyneon Ah no problem, I was sure I previously got it working only with display block.. but maybe I've gone mad for today :) glad the js fixed it tho.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IE8 does not support features of HTML5 that were not present in HTML4 (this includes the new elments `header` and `nav`). See the answer on the question [Does IE8 support HTML5 and CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497718/112968)

Try replacing the elements with the old, working way: `<div class="nav">` and use the CSS-selector `.nav`.

Comment: You are correct. Here is HTML 5, but you can't use it... sad. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**Background color not working on Internet Explorer (IE)**

IE apply some filter before rendering web page . that's why some page colors changed .

you can add following line in your CSS class to avoid it.

```
 filter: none !important;
```