# Why isn't my div changing color in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, internet-explorer

The below scenario is not woking in IE.

Styles:

```
.tabmenu {
    background-color: #990000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    left: 59%;
    border-top-left-radius: 10em;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    min-width: 75px;
    max-width: 150px;           
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    height: auto !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In .cshtml file

```
<div class="tabmenu" style="width:100px;" onclick="btnCommonOnClick()" id="btnCommon">Common</div>
<div class="tabmenu" style="background-color:#999999!important;"  onclick="EquipmentSpecificOnClick(1)" id="btnEquipment">Specific</div>   
<div class="tabmenu" style="background-color:#999999!important;width:100px;" onclick=" btnUnassignedonClick(this)" id="btnUnassigned">Unassigned</div>
<div class="tabmenu" style="background-color:#999999!important;width:100px;" onclick="OrphanOnClick()" id="btnOrphan">Orphan</div>
```

First load the background colors are looking fine. When I click on any other div, change the background color of that div. For that purpose, I have given the code:

```
$("#btnCommon").css("background-color","#999999 !important");//grey
$("#btnEquipment").css("background-color","#999999 !important");//grey
$('#btnOrphan').css("backgroundColor","#999999!important");//grey
$('#btnUnassigned').css("backgroundColor","#990000!important");//red
```

Above code is not working in IE. The div color is not changed as red. still in grey.

Any solution?

Comment: Are you using Html5? And what IE version you are checking?https://stackoverflow.com/a/13439843/4248328

Comment: yes .. Html 5, IE 11

Comment: `$('#btnOrphan').css("backgroundColor","#999999!important");` have to work . it's strange that it is not-working.Try once `$("#btnCommon").css({'background-color':'#999999 !important'});` and so on for others (try on one first by commenting out others)

Comment: the last line code     $('#btnUnassigned').css("backgroundColor","#990000!important");//red       is not working.. That is the issue

Comment: Why do you have the `!important` flags? Inline element styles always take precedence over CSS

Comment: try like `$("#btnUnassigned").css({'background-color':'#990000'});`

Comment: You should never use `!important`. This flag will result in more problems then it solves. There are only rare cases where it might be of use (e.g. if you need to create a widget on an external webpage where you don't have control over all he css code) and even then you shouldn't use them. Use more specific css rules and correct order of the css rules instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can confirm with IE Edge,with the inline `background-color:#999999!important` the css does not get overridden.

If you remove the `!important` declarations it will work fine.

I added to an html page:

```
<div class="tabmenu" style="background-color:#999999!important;width:100px;" onclick="OrphanOnClick()" id="btnOrphan">Orphan</div>
```

and ran in the developer console:

```
$('#btnOrphan').css("backgroundColor","#990000!important");
```

But the background color did not change.

When changing the html to:

```
<div class="tabmenu" style="background-color:#999999;width:100px;" onclick="OrphanOnClick()" id="btnOrphan">Orphan</div>
```

and running:

```
$('#btnOrphan').css("backgroundColor","#990000");
```

the background color changes.

If you need to keep the `!important` declarations you can try defining two css classes:

```
.bg-gray {background-color:#999999 !important;}
.bg-red{background-color:#990000 !important;}
```

and markup your HTML like this:

```
<div class="tabmenu bg-gray" style="width:100px;" onclick="OrphanOnClick()" id="btnOrphan">
```

And to change the colors in your click handlers:

```
$('#btnOrphan').removeClass("bg-gray").addClass("bg-red");
```

Comment: In summary: Don't use `style=` or `.css('syle',value)` - always use classes.